# How can I check if a string has one of the characters "\" ":" "/" "_"?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need a condition to return `true` or `false` if the string contains or not this characters.

```
if re.match('^*_|:|/|*$', code):
    raise VCompilerIllegalCharacterUsedError
```

-- this is not working as it should  work

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want. So, basicaly I suppose you want to find the characters '_' or ':' or '/' or '\*' in any position between start and end of the string. For this you need to change some things. First, use 'search' instead 'match'. Second, group your character choices(everything between pipes). You should use 'r' modifier and escape character '\' before all the special characters you want to find. Maybe this example could be better re.search(r'^.*?(\_|\:|\/|\*).*?$',code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is slightly off and this is what you were most likely intending to do:

```
if re.search('[\/:_]', code):
    raise VCompilerIllegalCharacterUsedError
```

The regex pattern `^.*[\/:_].*$` would match any code having one of the characters back slash, forward slash, colon, or underscore.

Comment: Furthermore, shouldn’t this function use `re.search` without the leading and trailing wildcards, instead of `re.match`?

Comment: Moral of the story: don't take for granted that _any_ code in the OP be optimal.